# Jquery UI click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I have some links within div. If users click any area in the div, it should do something. But it should do something else if users click on a link.

How could I find out if the click is on a link?
BTW, I cannot use `onclick()` function on the link.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mydiv">
      do something<br />
      <a href="#"> do other</a><br />
      do something<br />
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.mydiv').click(function () {
          var ahref = $(this).attr('href');
          if (ahref == null) {
            alert('do something');
          } else {
            alert('do other');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nodeName` property to check whether the clicked element is having an `a` tag or not.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mydiv">
      do something<br />
      <a href="#"> do other</a><br />
      do something<br />
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.mydiv').click(function (e) {
          if (e.target.nodeName == 'A') {
            alert('do other');
          } else {
            alert('do something');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName*